Align figure against outside (or inside) edge
I am preparing a twoside document with wide margins, where I am placing both margin notes and figure captions (using the sidenotes package). I would like my figures to be aligned so they are directly next to the outside margin, and therefore next to their captions. In other words, I would like the alignment of the figure to be against the outside side, opposite to the spine.
Please enjoy my attempt to illustrate this concept:

What is the right way to go about doing this? Is there some conditional I could check using \if ... \else ... \fi?
